# Reverse order of bubble sort of null elements

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to reverse my bubble sort so all null elements are pushed to the end of array instead of the beginning as they're getting sorted now. Any advice on how this can be achieved?

```
            for (int outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < students.Length-1; outerLoop++)
            {
                for (int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < students.Length-1; innerLoop++)
                {
                    if (students[outerLoop+1] == null)
                    {
                        var tempObject = students[outerLoop+1];
                        students[outerLoop+1] = students[innerLoop];  
                        students[innerLoop] = tempObject;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Just modify your compare logic to evaluate `null` greater than any non-null value.

Comment: Where is comparison statement in your inner loop? Or do you just want to drop the null values to the bottom?

Comment: @Tarik Yes that's right. I want them at the bottom.

Comment: Within the if statement and block, you should only use the innerLoop index. You should check if students[innerLoop] == null

Comment: Do a regular bubble sort but in comparison condition check for nulls. If both elements are nulls then they are equal, if only one is null then treat it as greater value, if both are not nulls then compare them. Another approach could remove all null values, sort remaining non-nulls and add nulls to the sorter array.

Comment: You should use the debugger provided by the IDE to step through your code to figure out what happens. You also need as a new programmer to simulate your algorithm on a piece of paper to see if it works. BTW, do not despair or get discouraged. It's tough in the beginning but you will get a lot of satisfaction when things work like magic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
        for (int outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < students.Length-1; outerLoop++)
        {
            for (int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < students.Length-1; innerLoop++)
            {
                if (students[innerLoop] == null)
                {
                    var tempObject = students[innerLoop+1];
                    students[innerLoop+1] = students[innerLoop];  
                    students[innerLoop] = tempObject;
                }
            }
        }
```

This will not sort your array but only drop the nulls at the bottom.

In fact you can do away with the temp variable:

```
        for (int outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < students.Length-1; outerLoop++)
        {
            for (int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < students.Length-1; innerLoop++)
            {
                if (students[innerLoop] == null)
                {
                    students[innerLoop] = students[innerLoop+1];  
                    students[innerLoop+1] = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Note:
[C# 7 introduced **tuples**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples) which enables swapping two variables without a temporary one:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 2;
(a, b) = (b, a);
```

This assigns `b` to `a` and `a` to `b`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked fine! It's quite difficult as a newbie to get a grip on nested loops, which is so frustrating! Any advice on how to improve the thinking when using them? I use the debugger a lot and see how loops iterates. But when combining them I tend to lose context...

Answer (score 1):

There's a faster, easier and stable approach with `O(n)` time complexity:

```
  int at = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; ++i)
    if (students[i] != null)
      students[at++] = students[i];

  for (int i = at; i < students.Length; ++i)
    students[i] = null;
```

However, if you insist on bubble sort: we can implement it in a bit different way

```
  for (bool wrongOrder = true; wrongOrder;) {
    wrongOrder = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < students.Length; i++) {
      if (students[i - 1] == null && students[i] != null) {
        // At least 2 items has wrong order, swap them
        var temp = students[i - 1];
        students[i - 1] = students[i];
        students[i] = temp;

        wrongOrder = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following.  You have to test for outer being null and inner not being null :

```
            for (int outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < students.Length - 1; outerLoop++)
            {
                for (int innerLoop = outerLoop + 1; innerLoop < students.Length; innerLoop++)
                {
                    if ((students[outerLoop] == null) && (students[innerLoop] != null))
                    {
                        var tempObject = students[outerLoop];
                        students[outerLoop] = students[innerLoop];
                        students[innerLoop] = tempObject;
                    }
                }
            }
```